# jdbc connection error:sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: connection Refused

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, database-connection

I'm trying to connect sql server 2008 R2 database in my jsp application. When I try it in my local machine its working perfect, but when I deploy and host my application in server its throw exception like

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP 
>   connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: 
>   "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. 
>   Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host 
>   and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP 
>   connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

**Note:** I'm sure sqlserver configured ( All required Remote Configuration enabled) perfectly. even  I got this exception when firewall off.

Comment: Is the SQL Server running on the same machine as your application server? If not you have to give the ip address instead of localhost

Comment: Is the tcp protocol enabled in your database?

Comment: I don't know what "remote configuration enabled" means, but I am pretty sure it is not related to enabling TCP/IP on SQL Server